# Find amount of vertice of grade 3 or 4 in planar graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

```
A planar, loop free connected graph has
8 vertices of either degree 3 or 4
7 faces
How many of the vertices are either degree 3 or 4
```

Since its a planar graph I assume we use |V | − |E| + #(faces) = 2 and we change the formula to E = V + F - 2 and we get 13 edges. I'm not sure how to go from there .

Comment: I do not understand the question. The title says to find the number of vertices of degree 3 or 4 in a planar graph, but the definition of the graph says that there are 8 of them. Also, the line "How many of the vertices are 3 or 4" seems to be incomplete.

Comment: @RandyMarsh the question is how many of the vertices are of deegree 3 or 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know Euler's formula for a connected planar simple graph $G=(V,E)$ with $e=|E|$ and $v=|V|$:
$$
v+f=e+2,\tag{1}
$$

From $(1)$ we will get that your graph has $13$ edges.

Also we know the next formula (the "First Theorem of Graph Theory" or the "Handshaking Lemma"):
$$
\sum_{{v}\in{V}}\text{$deg(v)$}=2e,\tag{2}
$$

From $(2)$ we will have that
$$
\begin{cases}
v_1+v_2=8,\\
3v_1+4v_2=26.\tag{3}
\end{cases}
$$

Here $v_1$ is the quantity of vertices having the degree is equal to $3$ and $v_2$ is the quantity of vertices having the degree is equal to $4$. From $(3)$ we will obtain that your graph consists of $2$ vertices having $4$ degrees and $6$ vertices having $3$ degrees.

Comment: I dont understand why it becomes 26

Comment: @Snozye, $26$ is the sum of degrees of vertices in your graph. The "Handshaking Lemma" states that the number $26$ can be obtained by multiplication of the quantity of edges $(13)$ in your graph by two: $\sum_{{v}\in{V}}\text{$deg(v)$}=2e$.